# Angular ng-disabled one time binding with function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

one time binding for ng-disabled expression can be added like below: It works fine. No watcher is alive once isDisabled is resolved.

```
<text-area ng-disabled="::isDisabled"></text-area>
```

How can we add one way binding for ng-disabled with function. Tried like below but watcher was still present on the element.

```
<text-area ng-disabled="::isReadOnly(name)"></text-area>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like it.

```
<textarea ng-disabled="::{{test()}}"></textarea>
```

JS :

```
$scope.isDisabled = true;
$scope.test = function() {

    return $scope.isDisabled;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem in my case is, there is no method called `isReadOnly` defined and since it will result in undefined, the watcher will be alive always since it could not come to stable position as specified in the **[Value stabilization algorithm](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)** in angular docs.

> When digest loop is done and all the values have settled, process the queue of watch deregistration tasks. For each watch to be deregistered, check if it still evaluates to a value that is not undefined. If that's the case, deregister the watch. Otherwise, keep dirty-checking the watch in the future digest loops by following the same algorithm starting from step 1

Comment: I dont get your point. there is no method called 'isReadOnly' defined. what value are you talking about?

Comment: My question is  how was the watcher alive on `<text-area ng-disabled="::isReadOnly(name)"></text-area>`. Not  on the `<text-area ng-disabled="::isDisabled"></text-area>`.